# I used up my email quota for google apps script - do the emails queue

Tags: google-apps-script

I have sent more than 100 emails using MailApp.sendEmail within google apps script. Will the emails that didn't go out queue and go out tomorrow or are they gone?

I use the spreadsheet to have people sign up for something and a confirmation email gets sent. I just want to know if the confirmation email will go out tomorrow when quota is reset or should I email everyone individually.

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

No, the emails won't queue and the sendEmail() method would throw an exception if you have exceeded your daily email quota.

It is always a good idea to check the quota before calling the sendMail() method.

```
if (MailApp.getRemainingDailyQuota() > 0) {
    MailApp.sendEmail(message);
}
```